# Jquery weird tag <a> event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a CMS using metronic and also making some modifications. I have a weird problem with jquery.

I have a html syntax like this :

```html
    <div id="remove">
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" id="remove_img_127">Remove</a>
    </div>
```

Then I coded the click event function in Jquery like this :

```js
$("#remove a[id='remove_img_127']").live('click',function(){
    
    alert('test1');
});
```

Strangely, when the other button using anchor tag - let say 'show picture' button - clicked, it also triggered the click event function i coded above. FYI, This 'show picture' button display an html page which this html syntax

```html
    <div id="remove">
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" id="remove_img_127">Remove</a>
    </div>
```

inside the page.

I have tried many things, but still they trigger click event function.

Do you guys have the same problem and how to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: what other click events you've written? I guess the problem must be related to event bubbling. Without a clear details we can't answer precisely.

Comment: Do you have elements with same id `remove_img_127`? if so, `a[id='remove_img_127']` will work on multiple elements.

Comment: Should have "#remove a#remove_img_127" as selector i think.

Comment: No only one id inside anchor tag valued remove_img_127. Please read my addition information i just wrote. It might help you to understand my problem

Comment: The code posted in the question is correct. The problem was elsewhere and the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use *on* instead of *live*.

```
$("#remove #remove_img_127").on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('test1');
});
```

Regards.

Comment: No, still the same error.

Comment: Try _stopPropagation_ method, but would be great if you share more html.

Comment: Please read my addition information i just wrote. It might help you to understand my problem

Comment: How is the html of the "Show picture" button? Have the same id as the remove button?

Comment: please read my answer below

Answer (score 0):

My "Show Picture" button has HTML syntax like this :

```html
<a class="btn mini green-stripe btn-show-picture" ref="17">

    Show Picture

</a>
```

This "Show Picture" button trigger to display this form :

```html
<div class="portlet box blue" id="form_add_1" style="display:none;">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="horizontal-form" id="form1">

.........

<div id="remove">
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" id="remove_img_127">Remove</a>
</div>

......

</form>
</div>
```

the "Show Picture" button triggered this  Jquery syntax :

```js
$(".btn-show-picture").live('click', function(){\

 $("#form_add_1").show();
  
});
```

Whenever i clicked the 'Show Picture' button, it also triggered the Remove click event function

```js
$("#remove a[id='remove_img_127']").live('click',function(){
    
    alert('test1');
});
```

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the style of the "Show picture" button. For example if the button has more padding that it needs, then you click in the other button, you call the other event also.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: In your example is impossible that Remove click events triggers Show picture click event. For example if this button has strong styles (for example lot of padding or much height), when you click the "Remove" button, also clicks the  "Show picture". Its my opinion. Do you have the entire html?

Comment: I finally found the cause of the problem. I explored the entire source code, I found there's a jquery syntax that also triggered the Remove button. I don't know why the programmer before me do this sh*t. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad to see that your problem is fixed.

Comment: @MyNameIsAnz consider closing your question then.